# After upgrade .htaccess does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

My provider 1 day ago update server (I don`t know prev version).
Now rewrite does not work index was include, execute and redirect:
http://testdomena.com -> http://testdomena.com/index/index (that correct)
But after that i see:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index/index was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at testdomena.com Port 80
```

Address is correct, before update all worked.

Now my serwer look like that:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-108-generic x86_64)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.5.9-1

apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<directory /var/www/>
    options indexes followsymlinks
    allowoverride none
    require all granted
</directory>

<directory /home/>
    options indexes followsymlinks
    allowoverride none
    require all granted
</directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

testdomena.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName testdomena.com
        DocumentRoot /home/web/testdomena
        <Directory /home/web/testdomena/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# No www in url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://testdomena.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Maintain page
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* maintain.php [PT,L]

# Files and dirs are not welcome
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|styles)/?

# And we don't want to check www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.testdomena.com
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,L]
```

Parts from phpinfo()

```
Loaded Modules
core mod_somod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_headers mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426690/problems-with-htaccess-after-upgrading-to-php-5-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/372733/apache-file-negotiation-failed

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
The problem was that the /etc/mime.types file was replaced by the update and in the replaced file, the PHP part was commented out. When searching for it, I found:

```
#application/x-httpd-php                        phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

I had to remove the # from each line containing php-relevant stuff, then save and restart the Apache web server. That solved the problem without modifying the mime.conf file